# Laravel phpunit test stopped at network call

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, laravel-5, testcase

## Problem (SOLVED)

The test case hit an unexpected stoppage on network call, there are few more test cases before this function and all goes well, but the console hangs when the test process hit this `testMemberRegister` function.

## Updates

UPDATE 1: if I remove the $params, the call goes through.
UPDATE 2: The problem is not related to phpunit, the register flow generate huge database calculation.

## Environment

`PHPUnit 4.8.35 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.`

`Runtime:   PHP 7.1.3-3+deb.sury.org~xenial+1`

"laravel/framework": "5.2.*"`

## The Code

```
public function testMemberRegister() {
    $data = $this->registerApp();
    $client_token = $data->access_token;

    $this->log('Point A');

    $params = [
        'access_token' => $client_token,
        'contact_no'   => '12345678',
        'lang'         => 'en',
        'password'     => '12345678',
        'nickname'     => $this->getNickname('2'),
        'username'     => $this->getNickname('2') . '@example.com',
        'referral'     => $this->getNickname('1') . '@example.com',
    ];

    $this->log('Point B');

    $res = $this->call('POST', '/api/v1/user/register', $params);

    $this->log('Point C');

    if ($res->status() != 200) {
        print $res->content();
    }

    $this->assertEquals(200, $res->status());

    ...
}
```

## Console result

```
Point A
getNickname
getNickname
getNickname
Point B
```

Comment: Your code seems fine, whatever is wrong, it's inside your called action. Did you try to return anything at the first line of `register` action?

Comment: @veNuker Yea, seems like the register logic take long time on database query.